# Create a shared folder for group of users

Tags: permissions, ssh, users, shared-folders

I have created a group of users in my Ubuntu server system, so that each one of them can log in through an ssh connection with his username and password. Each user is "locked" in their home directory, and cannot "look up" to any other folder in the system.

What I want to do is to create a folder that will be accessible to all these users of this group, with full rights inside this folder for the users for the whole group, while retaining the rule that they should not be able to access any other folder in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about using setfacl? 
In few words, it would be matter of creating somewhere the directory (e.g. "share"), set users group (let's call it shareusers) as primary group for each user in it, set users group as owner group for your share (owner user being root) and finally use setfacl to define acls (something like

`setfacl -m d:g:shareusers:rwx /pathToShare` )

Don't forget to chmod 2770 your directory.

Silvia

Comment: If the users were set up in a chroot jail, you may need to create a symbolic link in each users' home directory that points to the `/pathToShare`